# Encrypting/Decrypting Entity 'Password' Field Before Insert - JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, encryption

The heading pretty much sums everything up, although I would like to get a deeper insight and any suggestions into the best possible approach to [Salted + Hashed] as 'Users' password field before the entity is persisted/stored into the DB (JavaDB). I am currently using JPA as my ORM, and this is the first time I have ever used it, so a little noob here.

I have done some reading, and from what I have found it looks like we should have a method marked as `@Transient` within the Entity which [Salted + Hashed] the password prior to storing it in the DB.

Please provide any feedback / examples how this is to be actioned.

Comment: Passwords should never be encrypted. They should be salted and *hashed*. Encrypting passwords is a bad, bad idea.

Comment: First read about hashing: it's by definition a one-way operation. So you can't unhash a hashed password. That's what makes it secure. So, given that your question is about decrypting a password, and that it's not possible once you use a hash (which is a good thing), your question can't be answered anymore.

Answer (score 1):

To hash a password, [look at bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Now your problem with JPA/ORM is that you need *two* (or rather four) password fields, depending on the situation:

1. A field with the current password
2. A field to validate the password during login
3. A field to store the old password when the user wants to change it (can be the same as #2)
4. A field to store the new password while the user changes it
5. A field to repeat the new password

The usual solution for this mess is that you store the password as bytes in the database.

When you need to check and change the password, you need a new object with more/different fields where the password is stored (for a short amount of time) as plain text. When you need to update the database, you hash the password and only save the result of the hash function.

Or to put it another way: There is no way to add JPA/ORM mapping to a password field in such a way that you can update it with a single `setPassword(String)` method.

Comment: Maybe bcrypt is not anymore the best answer in general http://www.faqoverflow.com/security/4781.html

Comment: @SubOptimal: The FAQ says that NIST suggests to use PBKDF2 but "they say nothing at all about bcrypt." If bcrypt was insecure, they surely would say that.

Comment: in the chapter "Why bcrypt is not optimally secure" the sentence "While bcrypt does a decent job at making life difficult for a GPU-enhanced attacker, it does little against a FPGA-wielding attacker." explains it. bcrypt it self is not insecure. Only nowadays hardware exists which can be used to run a successful brute force attack.

Comment: have a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2. In section "Alternatives to PBKDF2" the "weakness" (depending on the implementation) of both algorithms are mentioned. If you, for example, want to break an embedded system implementation of PBKDF2, there might be a chance to break it if your run the attack on a much more powerful machine.

Comment: @SubOptimal: I see several problems with PBKDF2: 1. It doesn't say which PRF should be used for good/optimal results. 2. The number of iterations is important but what is a good value? 3. What's a good key length? 4. It's an algorithm supported by the NIST which casts doubt on it because of the NSA scandal.